# how to call different views according to a recived state

Tags: android, progress-bar, view, android-progressbar

I have a an expandable list view, and the parent "group" row contains TextView "for Name" and ProgressBar "for RSSI". now the RSSI which represents the 
signal health could be 20%,40%,60%,80% or 100% and the progress bar should indicate the health of the signal.

so I created 5 progressbars with the value of android:progress="" differs according to the signal strength.

for an example,

```
if the RSSI = -70; I should display the progressBar with 20%

if the RSSI = -50; I should display the progressBar with 40%

if the RSSI = -30; I should display the progressBar with 60%

if the RSSI = -10; I should display the progressBar with 80%
```

so i created the belwo xml file that displays the progressbars withh different progress percentage.

now my question is, what is the recommended way call each progressbar according to the received RSSI

**xml**

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:padding="5dp"
android:paddingTop="10dp"
tools:context=".ProgressBarTutorial" >

<ProgressBar
    android:id="@+id/progressBar1"
    style="?android:attr/progressBarStyleHorizontal"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:progressDrawable="@drawable/progress"
    android:progress="20" />

<ProgressBar
    android:id="@+id/progressBar2"
    style="?android:attr/progressBarStyleHorizontal"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:progressDrawable="@drawable/progress"
    android:layout_below="@+id/progressBar1"
    android:layout_marginTop="30dp"
    android:progress="40"/>

<ProgressBar
    android:id="@+id/progressBar3"
    style="?android:attr/progressBarStyleHorizontal"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:progressDrawable="@drawable/progress"
    android:layout_below="@+id/progressBar2"
    android:layout_marginTop="30dp"
    android:progress="60"/>

<ProgressBar
    android:id="@+id/progressBar4"
    style="?android:attr/progressBarStyleHorizontal"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:progressDrawable="@drawable/progress"
    android:layout_below="@+id/progressBar3"
    android:layout_marginTop="30dp"
    android:progress="80"/>

<ProgressBar
    android:id="@+id/progressBar5"
    style="?android:attr/progressBarStyleHorizontal"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:progressDrawable="@drawable/progress"
    android:layout_below="@+id/progressBar4"
    android:layout_marginTop="30dp"
    android:progress="100"/>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 2):

I didn't undarstand, why you created 5 progressBar for showing progress, but, if you want to show progressBar, you should use `mProgressBar.setVisibility(View.Visible);` and for hide use `mProgressBar.setVisibility(View.GONE);`

[View.setVisibility(int)](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#setVisibility(int))

For access to progressBars, in my opinion, you can use some implementation of `Map` class. (`HashMap` for example)

If you want just show progress, best solution will be to use `ProgressBar.setProgress(int)`.

Answer (score 1):

I you want to add / show your progress bars dynamically in your code, you can use the method `set visibility(int VISIBILITY)` with the constant `View.VISIBLE` or `View.INVISIBLE`.

However, I think it could be better to have just one action bar and changing the progress depending your RSSI (use `setProgress(int))` on your progressBar.